# Função para calcular a média de duas notas em python

Tags: python, funções

Estou com dificuldade em criar duas função: uma que calcule a media de 2 notas e outra que diga em qual situação o aluno se encontra "aprovado", "reprovado",e "recuperação".

Meu código está dando o seguinte erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 18, in
>
> media = mediax(i,j) NameError: name 'i' is not defined

**Código:**

```
def mediax(x,y):
medias = (x + y)/2
return medias

a = 0
while(a != 'fim'):
 nome = input("Nome do aluno")
 mat =  int(input("informe sua matricula"))
 ano = int(input("informe o ano"))
 turma = str(input("informe a turma"))
 nota1 = float(input('entre com a primeira nota'))
 nota2 = float(input('entre com a segunda nota'))
 media = mediax(i,j)
 print(mediax(i,j))
 if media >60:
   print("aluno aprovado")

 if (media>=30) and (media<=60):
   print ('aluno em recuperação')

 if (media<30):
   print('aluno reprovado')
 a = str (input('para sair digite (fim) para continuar (enter)'))
```

Comment: é simples, como diz o erro "i" e "j" não estão definidas, deveria ser `media = mediax(nota1,nota2)`, que são as variáveis que estão definidas

Answer (score 0):

Você está chamando `mediax(i, j)`, mas onde estão essas variáveis `i` e `j`? Em nenhum lugar. Você está tentando usar variáveis que ainda não existem, daí o erro.

Você tem que passar as notas, ou seja, `mediax(nota1, nota2)`. Além disso, se você guardou o valor retornado pela função em um variável, porque chamá-la de novo no `print`?

```
media = mediax(i,j)
print(mediax(i,j)) # para que chamar a função de novo?
```

Em vez disso, imprima a variável que já foi criada. Não tem porque chamar a função 2 vezes para calcular de novo algo que já foi calculado:

```
media = mediax(nota1, nota2)
print(media)
```

Outro detalhe é que [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input(...))` é redundante e desnecessário. Se quer uma string, fazer apenas `input(...)` basta.

E para verificar se o aluno foi aprovado ou não, use `if`/`elif`:

```
if media < 30:
    print('aluno reprovado')
elif media <= 60:
    print ('aluno em recuperação')
else:
    print("aluno aprovado")
```

Ou seja, se a média for menor que 30, está reprovado. Se a média não for menor que 30, ele não entra no `if` e testa a condição do `elif`. Se ela for menor ou igual a 60, está de recuperação (e eu não preciso testar de novo `media >= 30`, pois se não entrou no `if` é porque com certeza é maior ou igual a 30 - se não fosse, teria entrado no `if`).

Por fim, se não entrou no `if` nem no `elif` é porque com certeza é maior que 60 então eu nem preciso testar isso de novo.

E na função `mediax` não precisa criar uma variável para retornar logo em seguida. Se não for fazer mais nada com ela, basta retornar diretamente o resultado da expressão:

```
def mediax(x, y):
    return (x + y) / 2
```

E não precisa dessa variável `a`. Basta fazer um *loop* infinito e só interrompê-lo com `break` se for digitado "fim". Ficaria assim:

```
def mediax(x, y):
    return (x + y) / 2

while True: # loop infinito
    nome = input("Nome do aluno")
    mat =  int(input("informe sua matricula"))
    ano = int(input("informe o ano"))
    turma = input("informe a turma")
    nota1 = float(input('entre com a primeira nota'))
    nota2 = float(input('entre com a segunda nota'))
    media = mediax(nota1, nota2)
    print(media)
   
    if media < 30:
        print('aluno reprovado')
    elif media <= 60:
        print ('aluno em recuperação')
    else:
        print("aluno aprovado")
    
    if input('para sair digite (fim) para continuar (enter)') == 'fim':
       break # se digitar "fim", sai do while True
```